# Mosquitto websockets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, websocket, mqtt, lets-encrypt, mosquitto

I have an VPS  with a mosquitto broker and a webpage hosted inside.
The webpage is running over https with websockets, we bought a .com  host to be able to get letsencrypt certicate. At the beging I tried with a certificate of [www.sslforfree.com](http://www.sslforfree.com) pointing directly to myweb.ovh.net and the webpage connecting to this url too.

In that case everything worked perfect, but I need a certificate that could keep for a long, and letsencrypt I thing that could be the solution.
I created a letsencrypt certicate pointing to the web.com and I put that certificates in my mosquitto.conf in this way

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets

certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/privkey.pem

allow_anonymous false
```

When I try to run my mosquitto I don't have response in the server side, no message in the console and I get an error in the web console "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" it seems that the certicate is not beeing loaded in the server correctly  or maybe the cert is not ok.

With the cert from sslforfree everithing worked ok. Could it be a problem with file permissions? I'm totally lost with this problem, also I dont know how to see if the cert is being loaded correctly in my server.

My mosquitto log is

```
1596462903: Config loaded from mosquitto2.conf.
1596462903: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8884.
1596462903: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8884.
1596462903: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1596462924: New connection from 88.9.162.109 on port 8884.
1596462924: New client connected from 88.9.162.109 as crfEquipo40 (c1, k60, u'crfEquipo40').

1596462924: Sending CONNACK to crfEquipo40 (0, 0)
1596462924: Received SUBSCRIBE from crfEquipo40
1596462924:     opi40/cmd/teclado (QoS 0)
1596462924: crfEquipo40 0 opi40/cmd/teclado
1596462924: Sending SUBACK to crfEquipo40
1596462925: Received SUBSCRIBE from crfEquipo40
1596462925:     opi40/evt/hora (QoS 0)
1596462925: crfEquipo40 0 opi40/evt/hora
1596462925: Sending SUBACK to crfEquipo40
1596462925: Received SUBSCRIBE from crfEquipo40
1596463066: mosquitto version 1.4.15 terminating
```

As you can see port 9001 is running but nothing is happening, I tried the same with the sslforfree certificate and the connection was ok, messages received in the port 9001 but with the letsencrypt certificate no response.

In my javascript console client I get the next
[image]

and also this one in the chrome security  panel
[image]

Comment: Edit the question to include the actual log output from mosquitto. Also check that the date/time is correct on the VPS

Comment: Updated the question.
The date/time is the same as my country, seems to be correct

Comment: You haven't included any of the logs that actually show the error

Comment: Connection refused means that either nothing is listening on the port you are trying to connect to or there is a firewall in place.

Comment: Updated. The port is open because I can reach the server throw the web.ovh.net.
Could be possible thay if I have ovh gateway service I don't have the port available throw the web.com url?????

Comment: Yes, if you are using a web gateway service it is only going to be exposing port 80 (http) and 443(https)

Comment: If a client attempts a connection, but fails to authenticate, there WILL be an error in the Mosquitto log file.  As hardilib says above, you log file example does NOT show us the error from the Mosquitto side.  Please update your post with the actual error part of the log file!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/fullchain.pem` rather than `/etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/chain.pem`

Comment: I get the same result sometimes instead of ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID I get the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with the same behaviour, no mesage in my mosquitto console.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means that Mosquito isn't running, that it's not configured to use the port you're trying to connect to, or that a firewall is blocking access to the port.